# what is mean KeyWord "Where" in this code?

Tags: c#-4.0

I am begging in c# . 
What is mean "where" in all this class? 
Why i am used "where" in code?
what is benefit about Where Keyword ?

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity
    {
    }

 public abstract class AbstractControl<E> where E: AbstractEntity
    {
        public abstract void Add(E entity);
        public abstract void Modify(E entity);
        public abstract void Remove(E entity);
    }    


public abstract class AbstractSQLServerControl<E> : AbstractControl<E> where E : AbstractEntity
        {
            protected SQLServerConnectionManager connectionManager;
            public AbstractSQLServerControl(string connectionString)
            {
                connectionManager = new SQLServerConnectionManager(connectionString);
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`where` is known as a constraint.  It makes sure that your Type Parameter `E` is derived from `AbstractEntity`.   If an interface was specified after the `where`, `E` would need to implement that interface.

Comment: `E` doesn't have to inherit it could be an `AbstractEntity`.

Comment: pardon my mis-terminology.  It must be derived from AbstractEntity or yes, be an AbstractEntity

Answer (score 0):

where is a constraint that restrict the allowed types for E

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is a [generic type contstraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx).

What it does is require that the generic type calling this method meets the restrictions:

void temp(T stuff) where T : class

means that T must be a class. The compiler would not allow you to call 'temp<int>(42)'

Answer (score 0):

`Where` in your case specifies that the Type Parameter `E` needs to be a derivative of `AbstractEntity`. I suggest you take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx about generics

Answer (score 0):

It's the constraint for generics, please refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28VS.80%29.aspx). In your problem, `where` clause declares that the generic type `E` must be of or derive from type `AbstractEntity`.

In essence, generics is one way of achieving some of the benefits of dynamic typing with the advantages of having static typing. Depending on practical considerations, a generic without any constraint sometimes is too loose or broad, we need enforce some type restriction in compile-time, that's where the `where` clause comes in.